# Why is bootstrap btn-outline-primary not displaying proper button colors?

Tags: button, bootstrap-5

I copied the radio button group example from the Bootstrap 5 docs page ([text](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/)).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ILyv.jpg)

I reduced the 3 buttons to 2 and changed the text to No, Yes.
Here is what it looks like in chrome with No selected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO0wn.jpg)

I expected the button to change when selected to background color blue with white text as it is in the bootstrap example. The button functions like a radio button as expected. The only thing I want to change is the selected button and text colors.

Here is my code:
`

No

```
<input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Yes</label>
```

`

Is there some additional code I need to add that is not shown in the Bootstrap example?
Has btn-outline-primary changed?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.